# Add characters to a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

I need to add in a **For Loop** characters to an empty string. I know that you can use the function concat in Javascript to do concats with strings

```
var first_name = "peter"; 
var last_name = "jones"; 
var name=first_name.concat(last_name)
```

But it doesn't work with my example.
Any idea of how to do it in another way?

My code :

```
var text ="";
for (var member in list) {
  text.concat(list[member]);
}
```

Comment: If list is an array, then don't use `for...in` but a normal `for` loop. More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in Btw. if you look closely at both of your examples, you can see the difference ( `name=first_name.concat(last_name)` vs `text.concat(list[member])`

Answer (score 195, accepted):

```
let text = "";
for(let member in list) {
  text += list[member];
}
```

Comment: A better way might be to get the keys from the object instead of iterating (`for...in`), and join on those:

`var text = "";
text += Object.keys(list).join('')`

Answer (score 74):

You can also keep adding strings to an existing string like so:

```
var myString = "Hello ";
myString += "World";
myString += "!";
```

the result would be -> `Hello World!`

Answer (score 11):

simply used the  `+` operator. Javascript concats strings with +

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want to use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), e.g.:

```
var text = list.join();
```

Comment: Only works for arrays. But I'm afraid that the OP uses `for...in` to traverse an array, so your suggestion probably works.

Answer (score 6):

To use String.concat, you need to replace your existing text, since the function does not act by reference.

```
let text = "";
for (const member in list) {
  text = text.concat(list[member]);
}
```

Of course, the join() or += suggestions offered by others will work fine as well.

Comment: This is a good solution because it leaves the door open for function chaining

Answer (score 4):

Simple use
text = text + string2

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It adds the same char multiple times to a string

```
const addCharsToString = (string, char, howManyTimes) => {
  string + new Array(howManyTimes).fill(char).join('')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#expression_interpolation)

```
let text = "";
for(let member in list) {
  text = `${text}${list[member]}`;
}
```

Comment: That does not look like what interpolation was meant to be used for.

Answer (score 1):

your array of strings (list) could work with map and join; (Also possible to additionally change strings if you want)

```
var text = list.map(i => `${i}`).join(' ')
```

would return *`First Name`*

but if you want to add more things around the name, above template also helps:

```
var text = list.map(i => `'${i}'`).join(' ')
```

would return `'First' 'Name'`

and in case you would want to have a sequence of names, separeted by comma

```
var text = list.map(i => `'${i}'`).join(',')
```

would return *`'First','Name','Second','Third',...`*