# How to include the variable in a JQuery when using FOR loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a loop that involves me going through an element in my html with jQuery. How would I do so? For example:

```
if (fieldType =='date') {
    for (i=0;1<4;i++) {
        $('#aor_conditions_value\\[0\\]\\[i\\]').val();
        //do some more stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is is that the 'i' in my jQuery is not being acknowledged.

Comment: I think you mean `i<4`, not `1<4`.

Comment: And also: `$('#aor_conditions_value[0][' + i + ']').val();` - there you go, your solution.

Comment: just concat the string $('#aor_conditions_value[0]['+i+']')

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add characters to a string in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754712/add-characters-to-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I think when you do a jQuery .each function you have its index, i.e. $(something).each(function(index){

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! i will show you my finished solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to make it `for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){`

You left out the `var` also you probably meant `i < 4` not `1 < 4` which will always return `true`.

Comment: cheers! you saved me possibly a long time of debugging there!

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand what you're going for. But, if you're trying to loop through elements with ids `aor_conditions_value1`, `aor_conditions_value2`, etc., then this should work:

```
if (fieldType =='date'){
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        $('#aor_conditions_value' + i).val();
        //do some more stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also mention any other changes made, like `1<4` is now `i<4` and potentially some more clarification on why this works, but essentially, yes, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
It was a mix between your(people of stack) answers and mine

```
if (fieldType =='Date'){
                 for (i=0;i<4;i++){
                     var logged = $('#aor_conditions_value\\[0\\]\\['+ i +'\\]').val();
                        console.log(logged);
                }
              }
```