# javascript object to string issue

Tags: javascript, json, string

I am using this code (from Harsha Jagadish) that does a quick little speed test to my URL of choice.  It outputs the expected result just fine

```
return this.each(function() {
    var g = foo();
    $(this).text(g).append("Mb per second" + newg);
});
```

But what I need to do is grab that same output to compare if it's greater or less than a specific number.  The issue is it's an object.  I tried `JSON.stringify` and a couple of things, but no luck.

What am i missing?

Comment: What variable are you trying to compare to a number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754712/add-characters-to-a-string-in-javascript this link might help

Comment: So $(this).text(g).append...returns the number I am trying to grab, but if i simply do 'var newno = $(this).text(g)' it returns an [object Object]